# PostgreSQL IF-THEN-ELSE control structure

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

Why do I always get the following error from Postgres?

`syntax error at or near "IF"`

I read [PostgreSQL: Documentation: 8.3: Control Structures](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-CONDITIONALS). First I tried to execute a difficult query (with subquery), but then I tried to execute a simple one like this:

```sql
IF 2 <> 0 THEN select * from users; END IF;
```

The error is still the same. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
IF 2 <> 0 THEN select * from users; END IF;
```

You cannot use PL/pgSQL statements outside plpgsql functions. And if this fragment is from plpgsql function, then it is nonsense too. You cannot directly return result of query like T-SQL does.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test(p int)
RETURNS SETOF users AS $$
BEGIN
  IF p = 1 THEN
    RETURN QUERY SELECT * FROM users;
  END IF;
  RETURN;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

When you would get some result from function, you have to use RETURN statement - plpgsql knows only function, it doesn't support procedures - so unbounded SELECT has not sense.

Comment: Oh, thanks for your reply too. No i just was searching on how to make one or another "select" depending on condition in  "IF". So as i found there is no way to do it in simple like this IF (SELECT ...) = 2 THEN SELECT... ELSE SELECT ... END IF;

Comment: Actually
    IF (select a from t) = 2 THEN
        NULL;
    END IF;
would work, the problem is probably that you are trying to SELECT something in a context, that does not return anything.

In this case Pavel made a perfect example. You can use `RETURN QUERY` taking into account, that you defined your function correctly.

Answer (score 5):

You're not enclosing that PL/pgSQL control structure in an [anonymous block](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-do.html) or a PL/pgSQL function.

For the SQL version of this control structure see the docs for [`CASE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-CASE).

Comment: CASE cannot be used at the top-level, though, only as a part of a SQL query. In other words, it cannot be used to direct behavior that isn't a part of another query already, which is what the original question seemed to want.

Answer (score 1):

You're not enclosing that PL/pgSQL. They need to be enclosed with [anonymous code block](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-do.html). Example for your code:

```
DO $$ BEGIN

    IF 2 <> 0 THEN select * from users; END IF;

END$$;
```