# what is the meaning of this postgres error: "ROWS is not applicable when function does not return a set"

Tags: postgresql

I am new to postgres and getting an error that I can't seem to find on Stackoverflow (?). I am trying to write a function that returns true when a person is qualified for a job and false if they are not. This raises "ERROR: ROWS is not applicable when function does not return a set." [Found some stuff in spanish](http://www.forosdelweb.com/f99/error-definir-funcion-946980/)--but nothing on SO. Can someone explain this one?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "isPersonQualifiedForJob"(pid integer, jid integer)
  RETURNS bit AS
'
        IF 
        (SELECT count(*) FROM "getSkillsForJob"("jid") "j" WHERE 
        NOT EXISTS ( 
                    SELECT 1 FROM "getSkillsForPerson"("pid") "p" WHERE "j"."SkillID"="p"."SkillID" 
                   )
        )> 0 
        THEN 
           return 0;
        ELSE
           return 1;
        END IF;
'
  LANGUAGE sql VOLATILE
  COST 100
  ROWS 1000;
ALTER FUNCTION "isPersonQualifiedForJob"(integer)
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In this line:

```
ROWS 1000;
```

you are telling the planner you expect about 1,000 rows to return from the function but it is declared to return just a single value, a bit:

```
RETURNS bit AS
```

Answer (score 4):

The message is quite clear, and the [docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createfunction.html) :

> ROWS result_rows
>
> A positive number giving the estimated number of rows that the planner
>   should expect the function to return. This is only allowed when the
>   function is declared to return a set. The default assumption is 1000
>   rows.

Your function is not returning a set of rows, but a single boolean, hence I don't know why you are adding that line `ROWS 1000` (copy-paste from other function?). Just remove it and you should be fine.

Comment: That would be another question but: the IF-THEN construct does not exists in sql language. Try PL/pgSQL instead. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10011862/postgresql-if-then-else-control-structure

Comment: Please dont ask questions in the comments and then remove them.

Comment: The reason is the pgAdmin (and possibly other tools) adds a ROWS 0 estimate to any function body. This appears to be new behavior, though I'm not sure when it was introduced, but it cetainly happens in pgAdmin 4. It tripped me up as I was writting a complex data processing function that returns void when I came across this error (and immediately found this question/answer).