# how do I return a bit in postgres

Tags: postgresql

I am new to postgres and trying to setup a function that returns a bit.

I keep getting the error

> Function's final statement must be SELECT or INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE
>   RETURNING.

I understand that

[Unless the function is declared to return void, the last statement must be a SELECT, or an INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE that has a RETURNING clause.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/xfunc-sql.html)

here is the code

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "f"(...)
  RETURNS bit AS
 DO $$
 Begin
        IF  someStuff
        THEN 
           0; //also tried select 0 //also tried return 0
        ELSE
           1;  //also tried select 1 //also tried return 0
        END IF;
        0; //also tried select 0 //also tried return 0
END $$
```

Where am I going wrong with the syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several errors:

- the `DO` is wrong in a function definition
- you are missing the specification of the language
- in PL/pgSQL you use `return` to return the function's result

So your function becomes:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f(some_value integer)
  RETURNS bit AS
 $$
 Begin
    IF (some_value = 1)
    THEN 
       return 0; 
    ELSE
       return 1; 
    END IF;
END $$
language plpgsql
```

But you should use `boolean` instead of bit to return true/false flags:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f(some_value integer)
  RETURNS boolean AS
 $$
 Begin
    IF (some_value = 1)
    THEN 
       return false; 
    ELSE
       return true; 
    END IF;
END $$
language plpgsql
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use plpgsql then do as in the a_horse's answer but if you don't need plpgsql do in sql:

```
create or replace function f(some_value integer)
returns boolean as $$

    select some_value = 1;

$$
language sql;
```

If the function is the one from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15661766/131874) then this will do it:

```
create or replace function isPersonQualifiedForJob(pid integer, jid)
returns boolean as $$

    select exists (
        select 1
        from
            getskillsforjob(jid) j
            inner join
            getskillsforperson(pid) p on j.skillid = p.skillid
    )

$$
language sql;
```

Checking for `exists` is much faster then counting since it is enough to find the first match.

Comment: Even better, but I think the obfuscated `someStuff`  "requirement" will turn out to be more complicated.

Comment: @a_horse I think I found the _someStuff_ and if so the sql version is still adequate. See update.